# How to I make synonym words be represented in the same way (same word)?

Tags: python, nlp

I have a text classifier using bag of words to represent the text. I have been thinking that maybe having words with similar meaning clustered together and having the same name would be beneficial for my classifier, I would decrease the size of my vocabulary and perhaps improve my metric. However, I am new to the NLP field and I have no idea on how to do it, can you guys give me an idea?

Comment: If you create a dict of word & encoding and if you encode words what you consider as "similar"  with same numbers, then basically you treat these "similar words" the same.

Comment: Are you asking how to do it manually yourself, or if there are existing tools or functions to do this for you? In the case of the former, please try some things and include a [mcve] with your attempts and results, in the latter case, please note that questions asking for tools, tutorials, or libraries are explicitly off-topic for stack overflow

Comment: It was indeed about tools or methods in nlp that could do what I asked

Answer (score 1):

You can use wordnet (e.g. [from NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html)) and try to replace each word with the id of the corresponding synset. It will decrease the vocabulary somewhat. And if you want to decrease it further, you can make the concepts more coarse-grained by using id of the k-th order hypernym (k is a parameter) of the synset instead of the synset itself.

Of course, you'll have to resolve ambiguities somehow (what if a word belong to multiple synsets? What if a synset has several hypernyms?).